# Security Log Formatting

Tags: powershell, event-log

I am having trouble figuring out how to format the log data from the security event logs in Windows. The logs need to be formatted and exported to a CSV file.

Output should be:

```
Number of Audit Failures: X failures out of X entries

   Most common Event ID: XXXX
```

So far I have

```
Get-EventLog Security -After '11/1/15'.... | Export-CSV "filepath"
```

Comment: It looks like you meant your comment to be part of your question? If so, you can edit your question to add it.

Comment: Please add an example of what you are getting and then what you want that output to look like. A CSV is not going to be a list, which is what you have as your example.

Comment: Based on my interpretation of this question, it seems similar to another question that was just posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33550273/counting-log-results-in-powershell