# Counting log results in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have an assignment where I have to pull information like "Audit Failure" & "Audit Success" from my Windows security log file and count the results of each ex.  total attempts, # of successes, # of failures and most common event ID.  I saved a .csv to my desktop to obtain the information from but i'm not sure how to get a running total of each.  So far I've only imported the csv file.

My code so far:

```
$FileName=import-csv -Path "C:\Users\Robert\Desktop\Audit Count.csv"
$FileName | Select-Object | Format-List -Property "Keywords", "Event ID"

$AuditSuccess = "Audit Success"
$AuditSuccess.Count
```

Comment: I tried this and it did give me some helpful info.  I'm going to try to tailor it for the info I need (ex.  successes, failures etc).  I'm assuming I need to set some variables for the data i'm looking for.  Its a start, thanks Benjamin!  $FileName | Select-Object | Group-Object -Property "Event ID"

Comment: For some reason, I cant specify my search to provide the count of a specific item, like Audit Failure

Comment: Use the `-EntryType` parameter for `Get-EventLog`.

Answer (score 3):

Try `Group-Object`. Here is an example of grouping on property `EntryType` to get the count of successes and failures:

```
Get-EventLog -LogName Security | Group-Object -Property EntryType

Count Name                      Group                                          
----- ----                      -----                                          
21911 FailureAudit              {System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntry, System.Di...
14132 SuccessAudit              {System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntry, System.Di...
```

Comment: I tried to duplicate what you did above to see if I get the same result after Get_EventLog -LogName Security | Group-Object -Property EntryType and I got      Get-EventLog : Requested registry access is not allowed.  Do you happen to know what that means?

Comment: It probably means that you need to run PowerShell as an administrator because standard users don't have access to security logs.